# How to integrate NativeScript with Angular CLI

Tags: angular, angular-cli, nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-cli

Is it possible to integrate NativeScript with Angular CLI so you can develop your application for web and native mobile?  I've tried Nathan Walker's [NativeScript Magic](https://github.com/wwwalkerrun/nativescript-ngx-magic), but cannot get a fresh application created with Angular CLI to work.  I get this error:

error TS5053: Option 'sourceMap' cannot be specified with option 'inlineSourceMap'.

when running 'npm run start.ios' out of the box after creating the app via latest version of Angular CLI and installing latest version of NativeScript Magic and following installation instructions.

I love the ability to have different view files for a given controller for web/mobile environments.  It seems this feature is what NativeScript Magic offers.  I'm assuming NativeScript itself does not support a web implementation (ala Angular CLI) out of the box?

Any help is greatly appreciated.  I need to figure out how to support web, native IOS, and native Android development from a single codebase.

Answer (score 2):

There is a great new seed which might accomplish exactly what you're looking for.
https://github.com/TeamMaestro/angular-native-seed

ps - join the NS slack community, the guys who write these things hang out there and help the community out quite often.